# Handle xhr through nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I just got into using nodejs and so far I like it a lot. However, I'm having some little issues into making it a middle-man server/client.

To clarify, I'm trying to use nodejs in the client side and it will be a middle-man between a server and the client browser. Essentially nodejs will appear to be a server to the client and will look like a client in front of a server. 
So, I got it to listen on port 8080 at localhost and any incoming requests are being fetched by nodejs.

My question is, how could I make a way for nodejs to analyze the request before it renders in the client browser? Any idea/link/help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the simple code that I have:

```
var request = require('request'),
   http = require('http');

// var url = require('url');
// URL.parse(string);

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var dest = req.url.substr(1, req.url.length - 1);
    //console.log(dest);
    request.get({uri: dest}, function (err, response, html) {
            console.log(html);
            console.log(response);
            res.end(html);
    });
    console.log('fetched from ' + req.url);
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what you actually need is a *http proxy*... Have you looked at [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy)? It lets you customize the behavior, but provides all the required functionality, including support for WebSockets.

Answer (score 1):

@alienhard is correct that you are basically wanting a reverse proxy but I wouldn't be quick to reach for a library as he suggested. This is pretty easy to do with node.

```
var http = require("http")
var util = require("util")

http.createServer(function(req, rsp){

    var options = {
      host: 'www.google.com',
      port: 80,
      path: req.url,
      method: req.method,
      headers: req.headers
    }  

    proxy = http.request(options, function(response){
      rsp.writeHead(response.statusCode, response.headers)

      console.log(response.statusCode)
      console.log(response.headers) 

      response.on("data", function(chunk){ 
        console.log(chunk.toString());
        rsp.write(chunk) 
      })

      response.on("end", function(){ rsp.end() })
    })

    proxy.once("error", function(){ })
    util.pump(req, proxy)
    req.on('end', function () { proxy.end() })

}).listen(3000)
```